# unable to hide the whitespace after hiding #Sidenavbox in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365

i am able to hide the `#sidenavbox` element in SharePoint using the below piece of code:

```
document.getElementById("sideNavBox").style.display = "block";
```

but once i hide it, its showing white space in the place where the `#sidenavbox` div element was present.

[image]

Unfortunately i am not able to see a way to hide the white space. Can someone help on the same?

Answer (score 1):

Use This two pieces of code to resolve your problem:

```
document.getElementById("sideNavBox").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("contentBox").style.marginLeft = "17px";
```

Comment: i am able to do it with a plane style file in script editor web part as:: <style type="text/css">
 #sideNavBox {DISPLAY: none} </style>. but as it doesn't suites my need, i go with editing the master pages. Again the above method also doesn't seems to work for me.

Comment: You didn't specify in your question that you want to apply it in your Master Page. Anyway you can go in **yourmasterpage.master** and search for a div that containt **sideNavBox** and add this to it style="display:none" it will be like that <div id="sideNavBox" class="ms-dialogHidden ms-forceWrap ms-noList" style="display:none" > and also search for contentBox div modify it like this <div id="contentBox"
 aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all" style="margin-left:17px">

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :

```
$("#contentareaLeftNavBox").hide();
```

**OR**

```
document.getElementById("contentareaLeftNavBox").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: yeah, tried. But still getting the same error. Also i do see a script <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
        var g_pageLoadAnimationParams = { elementSlideIn : "sideNavBox", elementSlideInPhase2 : "contentBox" }; in the master page. which was there by default i think. Tried removing it, but was getting js error.
    
        
        
        
        
        //]]>
        </script>

Answer (score 0):

If you using a team site can use this option to hide side bar without code:
[image]